# Automatically Playing video in listview/scrollview similar to facebook

Tags: android, listview, video, scrollbar, playing

I need Video to play automatically in listview/scrollview, if view contains video. This is ver much similar with facebook. If user scrolls down and visible area contains video that system will play video and if still scroll then it automaticaly stops that video. It should work like one video should play at one time.

Can someone help me on this ?

sources I have gone through:

1. [Play video in Android listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901693/play-video-in-android-listview)
2. [How to automatically play video in listview on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139568/how-to-automatically-play-video-in-listview-on-android-app)
3. [How to automatically play video in listview on android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139568/how-to-automatically-play-video-in-listview-on-android-app)

Thanks..!!

Comment: For ScrollView you can set a listener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948934/synchronise-scrollview-scroll-positions-android

Comment: there are methods for finding visible item position in ListView, you can check those visible items to start/stop playing there. For ScrollView, you need to find item's bound inside that ScrollView though.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet george thomas :|

Comment: did u find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the points

1. First you need to add a scroll listener into `RecyclerView`
2. Then through the listener update your `RecyclerView` adapter

   ```
   protected void onListViewUpdate(final int position, final Object object) {
       final RecyclerView view = mView;
       LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager)view.getLayoutManager());
       final View convertView = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
       int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
       int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();            

       if (firstVisiblePosition <= position && position <= lastVisiblePosition) {
           // this is the convertView that you previously returned in getView
           // just fix it (for example:)

           Thread thread = new Thread(){
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   super.run();

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           adapter.updateRow(adapter.getItem(position), convertView, object);
                       }
                   });
               }
           };
           thread.start();
       } else {
           // just update your data set, UI will be updated automatically in next
           // getView() call
           adapter.updateData(position, object);
       }
   }
   ```
3. From the adapter update the current visible view from `updateRow()` method.

Job Done :)