# Auto Play and Stop Youtube video in Listview

Tags: android, youtube

I have a listview/Recyclerview. Each rows contain Youtube video panel. I am able to display a list of videos in listview. So now user have to click on play button and stop for pause video.

But i am trying auto play one video at a time when it visible to user and auto stop when user scroll down. I looked at but not having solution .

[Automatically Playing video in listview/scrollview similar to facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33890738/automatically-playing-video-in-listview-scrollview-similar-to-facebook)

Kinldy help me!

Answer (score 0):

Add this library to your project

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.waynell:VideoListPlayer:1.4'
}
```

source : https://github.com/waynell/VideoListPlayer

Comment: Thanks for that. is it support to youtube vidoes?

Comment: try it , This library will help you to get auto play like Facebook app. other things you have to implement

Comment: If this helped , Vote my answer

Comment: Thank you very much ajay. i am going to use it and let you know.